# Primefaces calendar not calling setter method

Tags: primefaces

This should be simple but I'm just missing something. My PrimeFaces calendar field is not calling the setter method.  The getter gets called when the page is displayed, but the setter is never called.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="timeframeTabForm">
    <div style="position:relative; left:85%;">
        <p:commandLink id="explainTimeframeTabId" style="text-decoration:underline;" value="#{i18n['help-text-tab-label']}"
            onclick="PF('timeframeTabDialogVar').show()"/>
    </div>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="searchTimeframe" layout="custom" value="#{articleSearchFormBean.timeframe}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-hour-label']}"  />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-days-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-year-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-12-hours-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-7-days-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-2-years-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-24-hours-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-30-days-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-years-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-90-days-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-specify-dates-label']}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{i18n['timeframe-last-180-days-label']}" />
        <p:ajax />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="15">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt0" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="0"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-hour-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-hour-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt1" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="1" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-days-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-days-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt2" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="2" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-year-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-1-year-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt3" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="3"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-12-hours-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-12-hours-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt4" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="4" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-7-days-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-7-days-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt5" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="5" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-2-years-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-2-years-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt6" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="6"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-24-hours-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-24-hours-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt7" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="7" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-30-days-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-30-days-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt8" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="8" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-years-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-3-years-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputText value=" " />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt9" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="9" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-90-days-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-90-days-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt10" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="10" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-specify-dates-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-specify-dates-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="align-content:center;">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-dates-start-label']}" />
                <h:outputText value=" " />
                <p:calendar id="timeframeStartButton" value="#{articleSearchFormBean.timeframeStart}" showOn="button" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{i18n['timeframe-dates-end-label']}" />
                <h:outputText value=" " />
                <p:calendar id="timeframeEndButton" value="#{articleSearchFormBean.timeframeEnd}" showOn="button" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputText value=" " />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
            <p:radioButton id="timeframeOpt11" for="searchTimeframe" itemIndex="11" style="padding-left:30px;"
                onchange="document.getElementById('_listenerportlet_WAR_listenerportlet_:articleSearchForm:tabView:timeframeChecked').innerHTML = '(#{i18n['timeframe-last-180-days-label']})';" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{i18n['timeframe-last-180-days-label']}" style="padding-left:10px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputText value=" " />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<h:form id="timeframeTabButtonForm">
    <p:commandButton id='clear' value="#{i18n['tab-clear-button-label']}"
        update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}"
        action="#{listenerArticleSearchFormController.clearTimeframeTabButtonListener}" process="@this"/>
</h:form>
<p:dialog header="Timeframe Tab Explained" widgetVar="timeframeTabDialogVar">
    <h:outputText value="#{i18n['timeframe-tab-description']}" />
</p:dialog>
```

The snippet of the getter and setter methods are as follows.

```
public Date getTimeframeStart() {
    return timeframeStart;
}
public void setTimeframeStart(Date timeframeStart) {
    this.timeframeStart = timeframeStart;
}

public Date getTimeframeEnd() {
    return timeframeEnd;
}
public void setTimeframeEnd(Date timeframeEnd) {
    this.timeframeEnd = timeframeEnd;
}
```

The radio buttons all work fine and are getting to the backend, but for some reason the calendar fields are not.

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `<p:ajax>` ?

i.e

```
<p:calendar id="timeframeEndButton" value="#{articleSearchFormBean.timeframeEnd}" showOn="button" >
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you click submit button and validation is correct it will be called, primefaces calendar working as well. You can test it , delete/comment all code in web page, put only calendar and try to submit, and output value directly on managed bean, after add your code step-by step and test in every step.